# Querying data in Python based on the business day (8am-10pm) and weekdays only

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, numpy, pandas

My question is very much open ended and am looking for some advice on how to manipulate an array with the following format:

```
list:
[datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 17, 11, 32, 25),
datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 17, 11, 33, 25),
datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 17, 11, 34, 25), ...
```

I'm looking to manipulate the array so that only (1) business days are considered, then (2) only times between 8am and 10pm are considered. Do I use numpy or can pandas achieve this? Can the format of the list i.e. datetime.datetime be used or is this to be converted into another format?

I have tried splitting the epoch so that the date and time are separate. In doing so the following command:

```
myArray.ix[pd.to_datetime(myArray['Epoch']).isin(pd.bdate_range(start='2016-05-16', end='2016-06-15')
```

The Epoch format was date and time, so I just split this so that the myArray consists of now 'Date', 'Epoch', 'Value' as three separate columns. In order to better understand this command (which so far doesn't work) and how to use it, I've used the following debugging lines:

```
t = pd.bdate_range(start='2016-05-16', end='2016-06-15')
u = myArray['Date']
v = u.isin(t)
```

The problem is from what I see, the dates in myArray['Date'] with format yyyy-mm-yy are not matching with the dates shown in `t`, also with the format yyyy-mm-dd. This can be verified when looking at `v`, whereby the contents of this are all false.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [bdate_range()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.bdate_range.html) for selecting only business days (1):

```
In [96]: d.ix[pd.to_datetime(d.Date.dt.date).isin(pd.bdate_range(start='2016-05-16', end='2016-05-22'))]
Out[96]:
                 Date       val
0 2016-05-17 11:32:25  0.235264
1 2016-05-17 11:33:25  0.755800
2 2016-05-17 11:34:25  0.849591
3 2016-05-20 12:00:25  0.955704
```

and [between_time()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) for selecting times between ... (2):

```
In [97]: d.set_index('Date').between_time('11:30','11:34')
Out[97]:
                          val
Date
2016-05-17 11:32:25  0.235264
2016-05-17 11:33:25  0.755800
```

preserving original index:

```
In [99]: d.set_index('Date').between_time('11:30','11:34').reset_index()
Out[99]:
                 Date       val
0 2016-05-17 11:32:25  0.235264
1 2016-05-17 11:33:25  0.755800
```

Sample Data Frame:

```
In [98]: d
Out[98]:
                 Date       val
0 2016-05-17 11:32:25  0.235264
1 2016-05-17 11:33:25  0.755800
2 2016-05-17 11:34:25  0.849591
3 2016-05-20 12:00:25  0.955704
4 2016-05-21 13:13:13  0.301753
```

Comment: thank you for that! I'm on my way, I think, but not quite there yet. I rewrote the code to the following: modified_array.ix[pd.to_datetime(modified_array['Epoch']).isin(pd.bdate_range(start='2016-05-17', end='2016-05-22'))] The omission of "d.Date.dt.date" was because this did not originally work. I suspect though this could have produced why I did not receive an error message with this line of code, but there was no change in the dataframe (in this case "modified_array").

Comment: By the way, in order to debug and check the output, I tried to save the array to a file using np.save but this produced a file that I am unable to read.